# I am sending a sqlite3 query result through node js to the browser as json

Tags: node.js, database, web, sqlite

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

var db = new sqlite3.Database('Items.db');




app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
});


app.get('/', function(request, response){

db.all("SELECT * FROM Items WHERE id>1", function(err,rows,fields) {

    console.log(rows);
    console.log('This function will return a list of all stored items from database ' + rows);
    response.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
    response.send(JSON.stringify(rows));


});
```

});

But the browser is not any anything.

On logging the rows to terminal it shows undefined.

[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8PMv.png)

I think the rows is not fetching results from the db.I think there might be problem in the path where db is located. Can you tell where to place the db file?? Or if there's any other problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Likely cause

You're trying to open `Items.db` in the same directory as `server.js`. There is no file named `Items.db` in the directory, so a new empty database `Items.db` is created.

Change

```
var db = new sqlite3.Database('Items.db');
```

to

```
var db = new sqlite3.Database('relative_path_to/Items.db');
```

Where `relative_path_to` is the relative path from `server.js` to `Items.db`.

You can get the same result by moving `Inputs.db` to the same directory as `server.js`.

### Alternative cause

`Items.db` has no table `Items`.

Make sure `Items.db` has a table with that name.

```
sqlite3 Items.db
sqlite> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Items (id INTEGER);
sqlite> .exit
```

Comment: I've populated Items.db with data, so that's not a problem. I'll check on the path as u suggested and let u know.

Comment: I added the Items.db in same level directory as server.js and it's working now. Thanks!!